# Understanding SPI CPOL and CPHA

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, spi

I have been studying about SPI and would like to clarify few more things:

**1.**
I am trying to understand about CPOL and CPHA in particular:
[image]

I have a device (MCP41 that I want to write SPI drivers for). The datasheet can be found here:
https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/11195c.pdf

According to the timing diagram:
[image]

It mentions that Data is always latched in on the rising edge of the SCK. Is that supposed to give me any hints about CPHA?

It also mentions that the Data is always clocked out of the SO pin after the falling edge of SCK. Since it mentions falling edge of the SCK, I understand that the CPHA for this device should be set to 1, is that correct?

**2** What if I have 2 SPI devices connected to the same SPI bus. One device requires CPOL = 0, CPHA = 0 and the other device requires CPOL = 0 and CPHA = 1. Does that mean it will not be possible to communicate with both devices via single SPI bus?

Comment: SPI is always tiresome to use because of the poor standardization and badly written datasheets like the one you linked... First of all, the clock in that pic idles low so you must use CPOL=0. Then I _guess_ that "always latched in on the rising edge" means CPHA=0 but they also seem to run MISO one bit length later than MOSI, which is exotic. With bad parts and bad documentation like this, it often ends up with always trial & error.

Comment: @Lundin: This is absolutely text book mode 0.  There is nothing exotic here.  MOSI isn't one bit later, it is one bit ***earlier***, it outputs the data on the second (falling) edge of the preceding bit, in order to be ready for the first (rising) edge of the next bit.  This is absolutely normal on any part using CPHA=0.

Comment: @TomV And that's what I wrote?

Comment: CPOL and CPHA are an afterthought perhaps meant to make life easier but instead made life worse, there are actually 8 combinations not 4.  The failure is assuming that the two buses are connected (miso and mosi for a two data line implementation of spi), assume they are not.  And thinking that the in and out are sampled and sent on the same clock edge, which in real world devices they are not, historically.  Because folks think this matters now they have controllers that only have these two settings instead of separate settings and it is painful to work with some devices.

Comment: Please add a credit to the question indicating that the first image in the question is from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface#/media/File:SPI_timing_diagram2.svg. And please also add a credit for the second image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timing diagram shows that this device requires SPI mode 0: CPOL=0 CPHA=0.

The way to read the diagram is that the clock idles low, so CPOL=0.  The data is sampled (called "latched" above) on the rising edge.  This is the first edge when starting low so CPHA=0 (the rising edge would be the second edge if starting high).

The comment about output data on the falling edge simply means that the device outputs the **next** data starting on the second edge of the preceding pulse, this way it is ready in time for the first edge of the **next** clock pulse.

For your second question, yes you can mix different clock modes (polarity, phase and speed) on the same bus, as long as you make all the changes when no device is selected, ie: when all chip-selects are high.  You may want to even change the mode of the chip select pins momentarily to GPIO while you deconfigure and reconfigure the SPI peripheral (I'm never sure what alt-function pins will output while you are messing with the registers of a disabled peripheral).